# Windows Phone access NetworkUsage

Tags: networking, windows-phone-8, usage-statistics

I'm wondering if is it possible to retrieve network usage from a Windows Phone App. I know this is possible in Android and iOS.

For WP, searching the docs I found this class: `Windows.Networking.Connectivity` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.aspx)
From there I saw the `NetworkUsage` class that can retrieve:

- `BytesReceived`: Read-only - Indicates the number of bytes received by the connection of a specific period of time.
- `BytesSent`: Read-only - Indicates the number of bytes sent by a connection over a specific period of time.
- `ConnectionDuration`: Read-only - Indicates the duration of connectivity.

But as I am not a WP developer I can't understand if this is a public API or not... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It's public: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh465162.aspx

Here is a working C# example:

```
//Set end Time to now
var currTime = DateTime.Now;

//Set start Time to 1 hour before current time
var startTime = currTime - TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

//Get the ConnectionProfile that is currently used to connect to the Internet
var connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
var localUsage = await connectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync(startTime, currTime, DataUsageGranularity.Total, new NetworkUsageStates());

foreach (var usage in localUsage)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Local Data Usage: \n\r"
        + "Bytes Sent: " + usage.BytesSent + "\n\r"
        + "Bytes Received: " + usage.BytesReceived + "\n\r");
}
```

Gives me:

> `Local Data Usage:`
>   `Bytes Sent: 757658`
>   `Bytes Received: 917693`

Comment: Thanks a lot, in the article you link I found a JavaScript example, that mean that I can access that data directly from Javascript?

Comment: .NET supports many programming languages: C#, C++, VB, F#, Javascript. You can use any of them to make an application for Windows Store. But the example I gave you was specific for Windows Phone Silverlight, and Windows Phone Silverlight only accepts C#, not Javascript.